# Bluetooth Sends Sensor Data Only once

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, accelerometer

So for my research, I have to send accelometer data to an arduino mega as a constant stream. I have the module connected to the arduino via serial. However, when I ran the code, it only runs once. I tried to place the Bluetooth connect part of the code inside my on accuracy change part of my code, but it keeps freezing the device. Here's my code:

```
package com.example.arduino_bluetooth2;

//=================================================================================================
//Imports
//=================================================================================================
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    // Setup necessary sensor objects
    private Sensor acc;
    private SensorManager sm;
    private TextView t1;
    private double value;
    // Bluetooth Object
    private BluetoothAdapter bAdapter;
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private BluetoothSocket mmServerSocket;
    private OutputStream btoutput;
    private static final UUID SPP_UUID = UUID
            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static final int DISCOVERY_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        accelerometer_initialization();
        bluetooth_initialization();
    }

    // Setsup the accelerometer object
    private void accelerometer_initialization() {
        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        acc = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sm.registerListener(this, acc, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    // Setup bluetooth object
    private void bluetooth_initialization() {
        bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE),
                DISCOVERY_REQUEST);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        bAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        value = event.values[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    }

    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (new String(device.getName()).equals("BT UART")) {
                    bAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                    try {
                        BluetoothSocket test = null;
                        test = device
                                .createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
                        mmServerSocket = test;
                        mmServerSocket.connect();
                        String message = Double.toString(value);
                        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
                        btoutput = mmServerSocket.getOutputStream();
                        btoutput.write(send);
                        btoutput.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you should creating and connecting the bluetooth socket in the broadcast receiver.  I do the bluetooth connection management in the onResume() of the activity.

Also I use a thread to manage getting data from the serial data connection between the arduino and the device, it is spawned off and runs continuously in the background.  There is a write method to send data out that i call from the activity

```
    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(String message) {
        System.out.println("...Data to send: " + message + "...");
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");     
          }
    }
```

then the run() method of the tread takes care of getting data back

See my answer in this thread for an example
[Error with receiving xml strings via bluetooth in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053358/error-with-receiving-xml-strings-via-bluetooth-in-android/15055201#15055201)

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Check out this page from arduino: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Loop
The problem is that it only goes once because it is not in a loop that continues forever until the device is shut off or told otherwise.