# Bluetooth Chat and Android - Bad data received

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, chat

I have a problem receiving data from my Arduino using the Bluetooth sample App.

My basic Arduino code sends some data at regular intervals.  I have tried various baud rates.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print( 1234 );
  delay(1000);
}
```

The data received in the Bluetooth Chat app sometimes gets split into 2 parts and sometimes the first part is wrong. I get data like the following (my bluetooth device is named HC05):

```
HC05: 1
HC05: 234
HC05: 12
HC05: 34
HC05: 1234
HC05: 2
HC05: 234
HC05: 34
HC05: 34
```

How can I fix this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use println() instead of print() on the Arduino side.
then you can look for the end of line character on the android side to make sure you get the whole line.

Here is a link to a similar question with my example code: [Error with receiving xml strings via bluetooth in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053358/error-with-receiving-xml-strings-via-bluetooth-in-android/15055201#15055201)